# PHP - Buy N items N items free

Tags: php, math, calculation

I'm trying to write a script for following problem.

Admin can add offer like buy N numbers of products and Get N number of products for free from selected products;
I need count of free products from total products

Example :

1. Buy 1 Get 1 Free;
2. Buy 1 Get 2 Free;
3. Buy 2 Get 1 Free;
4. Buy 4 Get 3 Free;

Here is the code i wrote

I have added loop in code to validate my formula on multiple quantities you can change offer conditions by changing the top variables.

[Temporary Fiddle](https://www.tehplayground.com/RX5jLPvyDBzePro3)

```
$buy = 1;
$get = 2;
$free= 0;
$sum = $buy + $get;

for($qty=1;$qty<=100;$qty++)
{
    if($buy >= $get){
        $free= (int) round(($qty/$sum), PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
    }else if($buy < $get){
        $free= (int) round(($qty/$sum), PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
    }
    
    $free*= $get;
     
    echo "Result = Qty = ".$qty." Free = ".($free)."\n";
   
}
```

Problem with code is that when there are 2 products in cart p1(qty=1) && p2(qty=1) free counter should be 1 but i'm getting 0

Comment: The code makes no sense. You have a loop, but a static condition which will ALWAYS go to the second branch, because 1 ($buy) < 2 ($get) - and this _never_ changes.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: created loop to validate this formula on multiple quantities ;

Comment: Isn't the problem, that you swapeed contents of buy and get variables? For what i see in your code the rest, it looks fine and in fiddle does what you have asked :/

Comment: Look in fiddle when qty is 2 free item should be 1 but i'm getting zero;

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is what i wanted;**

```
function get_free_products($qty,$buy,$get)
{
    $free = 0;
    $bought = 0;
    $skip = 0;

    for($i=1;$i<=$qty;$i++)
    {
        if($skip)
        {
            $free+=1;
            $skip-=1; 
            continue;
        }
        
        $bought+=1;
        
        if($bought==$buy)
        {
            $skip = $get;
            $bought=0;
        }
        
    }

    return $free;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).